# How can I render a result row using the Views API

Tags: views

I'm trying to render the rows in a view manually using the Views API. The style plugin is the "Unformatted" plugin. This is my code:

```
<?php
$view = views_get_view('nearme');
$view->execute('default');
$view->preview();

$renderer = $view->style_plugin->row_plugin;
foreach ($view->result as $row) {
  echo $renderer->render($row);
}
?>
```

This code almost works - it renders essentially a blank row. My "Global: custom text" field is rendered, as are some generic labels and field HTML, but the actual values from $view->result are not interpolated.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The tokens in views requires $view->row_index to be set to be able to get the right rendered fields.

```
$view = views_get_view('nearme');
$view->execute('default');
$view->preview();

$renderer = $view->style_plugin->row_plugin;
foreach ($view->result as $index => $row) {
  $view->row_index = $index;
  echo $renderer->render($row);
}
```